# There is a new meta tag setting to trim content from a token. How do I use it?

Tags: 9, meta-tags

[This](https://www.drupal.org/docs/contributed-modules/metatag/frequently-asked-questions) and [this](https://www.drupal.org/project/metatag/issues/2958193) site says there is a new Meta tag trim feature, but I have looked everywhere where I can think of and can't see an example of how to use it.

Does anyone know how to use that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The trimming options are at `/admin/config/search/metatag/settings` and appear as described in the documents you linked in the question. Set a value for the abstract, description, or title tag, then save the configuration.

Comment: I went there, but there only seems to be options to turn on/off the metatags. I have included in my question what I see when I look under the content type I am working with. Thanks!

Comment: NVM! I found it!